# How do I do bulk geocoding against the MapQuest geocoder using PHP?

Tags: php, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding, mapquest

Is there a person who uses MapQuest as geocode service ?

What i need is simple function that you pass the address and it gets the lat and lng inside it as results, just them nothing else needed.

For example google maps api uses this one :

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var value1    = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      var value2    = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
..
```

What should be the equivalent to using map quest ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The [MapQuest Geocoding Web Service](http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/) works in a similar way.  Basically, you would need to write a script that passes the address to the web service and then parses the response.  You can loop through the response and get the latitude and longitude from it.

MapQuest has a [demo page](http://www.mqdemo.com/brian/) as well as [forums](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/info/forums) on the [MapQuest Developer Network](http://developer.mapquest.com/) site.

Hope this helps!